# "Unable to prove `expr` literally..." error when trying to compare a symbol inside a function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I just started learning MATLAB and I'm trying to normalize a `bump` function given by

```
function b = bump(x)
region1 = abs(x) < 1
b(region1) = (exp(-1./(1 - x(region1).^2)))
region2 = abs(x) >= 1
b(region2) = 0
end
```

To do this, I need to divide by the definite integral from -1 to 1. However, when I input

```
syms x;
int(bump(x), -1, 1)
```

I get a long error message, which says

> Error using symengine (line 58)
>     Unable to prove 'abs(x) < 1' literally. To test the statement mathematically, use isAlways.
>
> Error in sym/subsindex (line 1554)
>     X = find(mupadmex('symobj::logical',A.s,9)) - 1;
>
> Error in sym>privformat (line 2357)
>     x = subsindex(x)+1;
>
> Error in sym/subsref (line 1578)
>     [inds{k},refs{k}] = privformat(inds{k});
>
> Error in bump (line 3)
>     b(region1) = (exp(-1./(1 - x(region1).^2)))

I tried replacing `abs(x)<1` with what I think is the suggested `isAlways(abs(x)<1)`, and that removes the error, although it gives the wrong answer (it says the integral is zero).

I don't understand what does the error message means.

Comment: Are you using symbolic objects on purpose?

Comment: @EitanT: if he's just learning MATLAB, then I'd guess "no".

Comment: @nneonneo I'm trying not to put words in the OP's mouth, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Eitan is right. My learning MATLAB consists of my Googling "matlab integrate" and seeing what comes up. So, this probably isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syms x` defines `x` as a symbolic variable, invoking symbolic computation on `x`. This probably isn't what you want.

Instead, define `x` as some kind of input matrix, e.g. `x = zeros(3);`. Or, to do numeric integration, use the [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function:

```
integral(@bump, -1, 1)
```

Comment: I changed `x` to `x = -2:.01:2`, but now it says 

`Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.` What does this mean?

Comment: Ah. I see now. You want an integral, which requires a function. You saw the symbolic documentation first so you didn't see the numeric integration function right after that. I added an example for `integral`.