# "Unable to prove literally" error when trying to create a symbolic function based on an existing function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, inverse

I need to find inverse of virtual value function of lognormal random variables. This is what I tried to do:

```
syms flogn(x,p1,p2)
% assume(p2<=0);             %Adding this doesn't change the error
flogn(x,p1,p2) = x - logncdf(x,p1,p2,'upper')/lognpdf(x,p1,p2);
glogn = finverse(flogn,x);
```

But I got the error:

```
Error using symengine
Unable to prove 'p2 <= 0' literally. Use 'isAlways' to test the statement mathematically.

Error in sym/subsindex (line 810)
                X = find(mupadmex('symobj::logical',A.s,9)) - 1;

Error in sym/privsubsasgn (line 1085)
                L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 922)
            C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});

Error in logncdf>locallogncdf (line 73)
sigma(sigma <= 0) = NaN;

Error in logncdf (line 47)
[varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = locallogncdf(uflag,x,varargin{:});

Error in Untitled5 (line 3)
flogn(x,p1,p2) = x - logncdf(x,p1,p2,'upper')/lognpdf(x,p1,p2);
```

I also tried with beta distribution, and got a similar error. How can I use `logncdf` with symbolic variables?

Comment: This issue is similar to [symbolic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42295215/7105378).

Comment: This issue is **very** similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18966576/7105378).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you could have minimalize your sample code even more, like this:

```
syms flogn(x,p1,p2)
flogn(x,p1,p2) = logncdf(x,p1,p2);
```

It's shorter, produces the same error and helps us to focus on the source of the error message.

---

So, the error doesn't come from trying to inverse a function, but from trying  to use an existing function for *numerical calculations* with symbolic variables.

The error comes from the fact that you want to create a symbolic function `flogn` based on existing function `logncdf`, and `logncdf` has a multiple comparisons.

With the command `edit logncdf`, you can read the source code of the function and see comparison at lines 73 and 76.

```
% Return NaN for out of range parameters.
sigma(sigma <= 0) = NaN;

% Negative data would create complex values, which erfc cannot handle.
x(x < 0) = 0;
```

Matlab cannot compare symbols so it throws errors.

Depending on what you really need, you can have different solutions.

- Do you really need to symbolize the function `flogn`? Couldn't you just write it as a `function` then calculate the inverse of it (if it can be inversed...)?
- If you really want to keep the symbolization, you can also rewrite your own function `logncdf` (with another name) so it does not have the comparisons. But it's still not guaranteed that you will find an inverse.

Comment: Thanks for the minimization suggestion. Will keep in mind the next time.

Comment: I don't need to symbolize the function. But how do I compute the inverse without it? For now, I have circumvented the problem, but I would still like to know your thoughts on this. Is creating an array X of numbers and then computing y = fzero(f(x)-x) on all x in X the only way?

Comment: @cauthon14 Hi! I would recommend using [`fzero`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) just like you said. I suggest reading [this](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/286749-find-inverse-of-a-function) or a lot of questions about similar topics have been ask here, in SO. If you still don't find a solution in existing questions in SO, fell free to ask a new question. Regards.